# c++: Using string.erase on a char*

Tags: c++, string, erase, arrays

say I have a pointer pointing to a `char array` as such the sample in the program:

```
string input = "bo1b";
char* = &input;
```

and then I want to get rid of that 1

I use a loop such as

```
while(i<strlen(input))
{


if (!isalpha(input[i]))
{
input.erase(i,1) <------?

}
```

something vaugely like that
I'm just not sure how to use c++ string functions on...a char pointer?
I do understand that in c++ that a string is just a char array, however exact usage and what not still passes me.

Answer (score 3):

> something vaugely like that I'm just not sure how to use c++ string functions on...a char pointer?

You can't.  Not directly.  If you want to operate on `char*`-style strings, you have to use the functions in the `<cstring>` header.  But there are several details to keep track of if you use those functions, so I wouldn't recommend that in general.

> I do understand that in c++ that a string is just a char array,

This statement is almost true.  A `std::string` is meant to replace `char*` strings, and as such it can do everything a `char*` and then some.  A `std::string` has, at least, a `char*` that points to a buffer, a length of how long that buffer is, and a second length of how much of that buffer's been used.  There's a good chance that it also has a smaller buffer inside the object itself ("small string optimization"), and a decent chance that it has some kind of reference count (the Standard is written to make "copy on write" a legal implementation, and many implementations take advantage of that, [although that may not be the right approach](http://libcxx.llvm.org/)).

If you want to use `std::string` methods, you need a `std::string`, which is easy enough to make:

```
std::string foo(input);
while (i < foo.size()) {
    if (!std::isalpha(foo[i])) {
        foo.erase(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Personally, I would write that (in C++0x):

```
std::string foo("hello 123");
auto itor = std::remove_if(foo.begin(),
                           foo.end(),
                           [](char c){ return !std::isalpha(c); });
foo.erase(itor, foo.end());
```

Or:

```
std::string foo;
std::copy_if(input,
             input + strlen(input),
             std::back_inserter(foo),
             std::isalpha);
// foo now contains what you were looking for
```

Many people prefer to use the `std::string` methods, so I can't say that my approach is necessarily better.

Comment: You can use `std::not1(std::ptr_fun(std::isalpha))` in C++03 if I'm not mistaken. :)

Comment: +1 - additional note: `std::remove_if()` can work directly on the `input` string without converting to `std::string` first. Instead of passing in `foo.begin()` and `foo.end()`, pass in `input` and `input + strlen(input)`.  Then instead of calling `foo.erase()` use `*itor = '\0';` to properly terminate the result.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the c-style string to a `std::string` like so:

```
std::string stringToEdit( cString );
// The constructor of a std::string can take a char* (c-style string)
```

Now you can use the [standard C++ string functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to manipulate this string, for instance [erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/), like you're trying to do in your code snippet.

Comment: in that event, this is part of a function that returns a pointer to the 'cleaned' string, so it would be effective enough just go &string and return that?

also in that conversion there, how to i reference that new std string?

Comment: Well you can use the `c_str()` method of a `std::string` when you want to convert it back to a c-style string. But be careful, you don't want to return a pointer/reference to stack allocated memory in the local scope of the function. I would convert your code to a more pure C++ form that returns an `std::string` (not a reference or anything though)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to convert into CString, you can use std:string functions as well, see the link below:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: so would I be casting it to a std:string temporarily or something a rather?

Comment: @HPM Not casting, creating a new object, a copy.